# In a custom function in std::sort() the interchanging of >(greater than) operator to <(less than operator) can cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the kruskal's mst algorithm.I am trying to sort the  edges in the vector edge according to the increasing order of the weight of each edge.But after sorting the complete vector a segmentation fault is occuring.But if I just change the 
<(less than) sign to >(greater than) in my **mycomp** function so that it will sort it in decreasing order it is executing correctly.why is this happening??I think here the strickt weak ordering is being maintained.Thank you.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#define all(container) container.begin(),container.end()

bool mycomp(const Edge* a,const Edge* b)
{return a->weight<b->weight;}

void kruskalmst(Graph* graph)
 {vector<Edge*> result;int i=0;
   sort(all(graph->edge),mycomp);

   }
```

Comment: Your `all` macro is a terrible idea. Use a range library if you want to just pass the container.

Comment: You are correct that strict weak ordering is being maintained in your comparison function.  The function is also dereferencing pointers, and your container probably has bad pointers.  Running the code in a debugger will tell you if the pointer dereferences are causing the segfault.

Comment: What does `Graph::edge()` return?

Comment: Please do use braces and indentation consistently, this code is a complete mess and much harder to read than it needs to be. For example your intentions with the `if(x!=y)` aren't at all clear, what lines of code are supposed to be executed if that condition is true?

Comment: This is not good example code.  If you're getting a segfault in `sort()`, why show code that occurs *after* `sort()` and almost no code leading to the segfault?

Comment: You're using `,` where you should be using `&&` (between `i<graph->e` and `result.size()<graph->v-1`) which will very likely lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @shuttle87 after the `if(x!=y)` the next line which is `result.pb(graph->edge[i]);` will be executed.Here I have used `pb` as a macro referring to `push_back`.

Comment: @Drew Dormann Here I have used the `std::sort()` from `<algorithm>`.I have added the custom function `bool mycompare`in it to sort the `vector<Edge*> edge` according to the increasing `weight` attribute of each edge.where an  edge has three attributes `int src,dest,weight`.

Comment: @juanchopanza `Graph::edge` is `vector<Edge*>`.Where Edge is-`class Edge
{public:Edge(int s,int d,int w);int src,dest,weight;};`

Comment: @Sat_sen There you go then. You are iterating over incompatible iterators because they iterate over different containers.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am iterating over the `vector<Edge*> edge`.And as i have told in my question that if I just change the `<` operator to `>` operator in `mycompare` function  it's executing perfectly without any segmentation fault.How is this possible?

Comment: According to what you have said and was shown in code before the edit, the `begin()` and `end()` iterators you try to iterate over belong to different containers. Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for the for loop:

```
 i<graph->e,result.size()<graph->v-1
```

uses the comma operator.  According to ISO standard 5.18 pt.1:  "A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discarded value expression".
This means that you loop, without taking into consideration if `i<graph->e`, so that you may go beyond the end of your iterator.

And yes, to solve this you'll need too replace the coma with a logical operator.  If `graph->e` is the number of edges, the connector should be `&&`.

Comment: Solution: It needs an OR there, not a comma.

Comment: @Jongware I almost forget to give the solution.  Thanks for the gentle reminder ;-)

Comment: Very good -- I was actually dithering between OR and AND. Seems I picked the wrong one :)

Comment: I have tried && operator.But it's still giving the same segmentation fault.As i have told in my question if I just make the '<' operator to '>' it's executing correctly and sorting the vector reversely without any segmentation fault with the same condition of the for loop.

Comment: Is your operator< overloaded ?